# Hibernate re-writes many to many entires?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a domain object that holds a collection of another object through a `@ManyToMany` annotaion:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "join_table", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id"))
    private List<B> BsList;
```

In the join table i hold additional data columns.

I noticed that when i work with the object that holds the list and call `setBsList()` the data i had in the additional columns is deleted. 
Does Hibernate re-write the rows in the join table each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the join table i hold additional data columns.

If you have additional data columns, it's *not* a join table. It's a table with two FKs which can also be PKs. And Hibernate is doing the right thing. So, you should instead create another entity representing this "fake join table", and map it accordingly.

Comment: Yes I am aware that this is not a "legal" join table, but there is no mapping to the join table except the above. Does hibernate identifies these additional fields and hence the behavior or does hibernate always do these re-writes?

Comment: No, if I remember correctly Hibernate deletes all the "links" and recreates them, instead of identifying the existing links and updating/creating/deleting the changes. So, while they may seem the same records, they are in fact new records.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `setBsList()`, you should directly modify `getBsList()` otherwise Hibernate has no way of tracking what has changed.

When loading, the actual `List` you get is a Hibernate-specific implementation which deals with the lazy loading and tracks what is added and removed, so that it can be correctly updated. If you replace this with a different list implementation it will delete the old one and only add then only add the new entries. When using Hibernate with collections, it's a good idea to make the setter protected so you can't accidentally do this.